# How can I prevent all update panels reloading when I click a button in one of them?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, updatepanel

I've got a webform with two update panels:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

<p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upl1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Button1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upl2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn2" Text="Button2" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</p>
```

If I click `btn1`, then the load event of `upl2` is triggered, as well as `upl1`.

I would expect only `upl1` to be loaded, since this is the update panel that contains the button.

Why isn't this happening, and how can I make it happen?

Comment: I think you need to use triggers to properly isolate the correct update panel - check out this MSDN tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Answer (score 1):

One pratice I always use when I work with Update Panels, is to set the properties:

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

And refresh the Update Panel only when I want:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some logic
    // ....
    upl1.Update();
}
```

Try applying these properties and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry. Both upload panels still reload with every button click.

Comment: Aren't these two UpdatePanels inside another UpdatePanel?

Comment: They shouldn't. But this happens when there are nested UpdatePanels and the parent is configured as `UpdateMode="Always"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a button triggering an `UpdatePanel`, and using `ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional"` didn't help.

I ended up using the following to force the button to do a regular post-back:

```
 ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(btn1);
```